# Codeigniter 3 on subdomain on godaddy shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

All
Please help me to upload codeigniter project on subdomain , my project is not working on subdomain, hosted on godaddy servers. I am getting errors. I am sure, you will help me. Please review my settings below:

config.php

```
$config['base_url']    = "http://www.example.com/example-subdomain/";
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
```

htaccess within application foler

```
Deny from all
```

htaccess within root of subdomain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Try with `$config['base_url']    = "http://example-subdomain.example.com/";`.

Comment: i tried as per your suggestion, but error is the same ! It is neither showing any content nor showing any error... I am totally confused what to do!!!

Comment: Do you have enabled subdomain? Have you made it on your server - can you test your `example-subdomain.example.com` with one self-contained `index.php` set in appropriate directory?

Comment: Hey please let me know did you get any solution?